# Button elevation is not shown because of parent's padding

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

In a layout like the following :

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:padding="5dp"
    ... >
        <Button
            android:alignParentBottom="true"
            android:elevation="2dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

The shadow of the `Button` is not shown because it is "behind" the padding of the parent.

In other words the `Button` does not automatically takes into consideration its elevation to add some space between itself and the parent's bottom.

How can I make it work ?

Set an additional margin for this button to be sure that elevation's shadow will be show properly ?

Thanks for you help.

Comment: you can add a `LinearLayout` before the button with `3dp`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can add `android:clipToPadding="false"` on the parent `RelativeLayout`.

This will make the parent not clipping it's child view drawing inside his own bounds.

Comment: Thank you sir! It was exactly what I needed. I can't believe I've been working on Android all this time without knowing this...

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer!